# When playing chess online, what does 1-1 mean?

Tags: learning, online-chess

When playing chess online, when your opponent says 1-1, what does 1-1 mean?

Comment: It's a typo. He or she meant 1-0 or 0-1.

Comment: Or you two have played before (you may not remember) and he has just levelled the score.

Comment: I think "1-1" is about the time control: 1 minute with 1 seconde/move increment.

Answer (score 4):

As your question isn't very clear, but by what you have mentioned about your opponent saying 1-1, i can say there are 2 possibilities.

He either means it as the score between you 2 such as, you guys have played 2 games and both ended in draw, considering half point to each player per draw, it's 1-1, or both player has lost 1 and won another so 1-1 again.

Or he might be saying it regarding time control of a game. 1-1 meaning 1 minute per player and 1 second increment per move for the whole game.

More examples for time controls are such as : 2-1, 5-2, 10-0, 15-10, etc. Where the first number indicates the time in minutes per player for the whole game and the second digit indicates the increment time in seconds per move per player till the end of the game.

Comment: Please care to accept the answer if you feel it has got everything the question needs.